# Retain the div shown after the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I created 3 divs that are displayed using input type buttons, these buttons are used to show and hide the divs that are hidden initially. In those divs there are forms that used to store data. Now what I am trying to do is to retain the current used div after submitting data in a form.

This is my jquery codes.

```
$("#add_exams").hide();
  $("#exams").hide();
  $("#add_accts").hide();

  $("#view_exam").click(function(){
      $("#add_exams").hide();
      $("#exams").hide();
      $("#add_accts").hide();

      $("#exams").fadeIn();
  });

    $("#create_exam").click(function(){
      $("#add_exams").hide();
      $("#exams").hide();
      $("#add_accts").hide();

      $("#add_exams").fadeIn();
  });

    $("#manage_accts").click(function(){
      $("#add_exams").hide();
      $("#exams").hide();
      $("#add_accts").hide();

      $("#add_accts").fadeIn();
  });

 //$(document).on("click", "#selectall",function(){ 
  $(document).on("submit","#submit_acct", function(){

       $("#add_accts").fadeIn();

  });
```

My html is something like this

```
<div id="content">
 <input type="button" id="create_exam" value="Create Exam" title="Click to create new exam."  />
  <input type="button" id="view_exam" value="Exam" title="Click to view exam."  />
  <input type="button" id="manage_accts" value="Accounts" title="Click to view exam."  />
    <div id="add_accts">
       /*forms goes here */
    </div>

    <div id="add_exams">
       /*forms goes here */
    </div>

    <div id="exams">
       /*forms goes here */
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to submit data, the div is not displaying, i tried to used a jquery that will display the div I want but it does not work, all of them are hidden. I just need to retain to show the current displayed div, Any Idea on this?

Comment: try adding event.preventDefault(); to your on-submit js and do ajax after

Comment: i think you have missed something

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you want to retain the **visible div** even after **post-back**. you can use a hidden field for retaining the div visibility. try the following code snippet for reference

```
$("#view_exam").click(function(){
      $("#add_exams").hide();
      $("#exams").hide();
      $("#add_accts").hide();

      $("#exams").fadeIn();
      $("#FiddenField_For_Current_Form").val("exams");
  });
```

And At page load Check the value in **FiddenField_For_Current_Form** and show the appropriate form as the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  switch($("#FiddenField_For_Current_Form").val())
  {
    case "exams":
             $("#exams").fadeIn();
             break;

    default :
            $("#add_exams,#exams,#add_accts").hide();
             break;

  }


});
```

Comment: had a problem with this.. <input type="hidden" id="cur_div"> I used this input type, and as expected is changes the value on click event, but it is still the same, I manually added value="exams" to the input, it works just fine.

Comment: Change from  $("FiddenField_For_Current_Form").val("exams"); to  $("#FiddenField_For_Current_Form").val("exams");